# Hibernate changes database change

Tags: oracle, hibernate, struts

I am using Struts and Hibernate 2.0 in my project. My database has changed from oracle 10g to Oracle 11g in my project.

Can you please tell me what changes do I need to make in my Hibernate configuration?

Also Are there any changes required in my Java code.

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid></property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data access logic is implemented in Hibernate then your code is portable. Meaning you really don’t need to change anything specific to database change in your case apart from Driver if its causing any trouble . For instance, if you are changing database from MYSQL to Oracle then probably need to change **dialect** part, Connection properties of your hibernate configuration file alone plus your database specific driver.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Sorry I had placed the wrong hibernate config file in this post before. I corrected it now. So do I have to change the Dialect name?

Answer (score 0):

Just update  driver (Jar file) to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't seem like it was configured to Oracle 10g , it shows MySQL.. 
Anyways do this to solve your question.
Just change the **Driver name** and URL i.e **connection string** and also change the **Dialect**
search for Oracle Dialect online and don't forget to add Jars!!! :)

Comment: Sorry I had placed the wrong hibernate config file in this post before. I corrected it now. SO do I have to change the Dialect name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to change the dialect name. Sorry I am posting another answer as I am not able to  add another comment.
Find for Oracle11g dialect name online,  **Dialects are classes that convert HQL(hibernate query language to actually Database query)**, it **may** say **ClassNotFoundException**, if this happens then just search for the Hibernate jar that has Oracle11g Dialect Class in it. As I am pretty sure that this jar is NOT available with the JDBCDriver jars that ORacle provides to connect to database.

***The Dialect Jars are a part of Hibernate***